# Can't add key to JSON object. No errors thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, toml

When I run the below, I get

```
$ node t.js 
{ "project": { "key": "DEMO" }, "issuetype": { "id": 10002 }, "priority": { "id": "3" }}
{ "project": { "key": "DEMO" }, "issuetype": { "id": 10002 }, "priority": { "id": "3" }}
{ "project": { "key": "DEMO" }, "issuetype": { "id": 10002 }, "priority": { "id": "3" }}
```

and the `time` key/value isn't added.

Can someone figure out why?

**t.js**

```
const toml = require('./toml');
const moment = require('moment');

const t = toml('non-production.toml');

let a = new Object;
a = t.Jira.pack.c;
console.log(a);

const time = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
a["customfield_11904"] = time;
a.customfield_11904 = time;
console.log(a);

t.Jira.pack.c.customfield_11904 = time;
console.log(t.Jira.pack.c);
```

**toml.js**

```
const TOML = require('@iarna/toml');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (filename) => {
  return TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
}
```

**non-production.toml**

```
[Jira]
  pack.c = '{ "project": { "key": "DEMO" }, "issuetype": { "id": 10002 }, "priority": { "id": "3" }}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `a` is still a string. Thus you can't add new keys to it. 
Parse it as JSON first:

```js
const toml = require('./toml');
const moment = require('moment');

const t = toml('non-production.toml');

let a = JSON.parse(t.Jira.pack.c);
console.log(a);

const time = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
a.customfield_11904 = time;

console.log(a);
```

---

This now yields

```json
{
  project: { key: 'DEMO' },
  issuetype: { id: 10002 },
  priority: { id: '3' }
}
{
  project: { key: 'DEMO' },
  issuetype: { id: 10002 },
  priority: { id: '3' },
  customfield_11904: '2021-03-12T09:39:15.259+0100'
}
```